# Symfony 4 migration for standalone bundle return No mapping information to process

Tags: symfony

I create a symfony standalone bundle and i map the entities using compile pass but when i run migration i get No mapping information to process

This is my compile pass code i also try many example without success

```
        $fileLocator = new Definition(DefaultFileLocator::class, array(
            array(realpath(__DIR__ . '/Resources/config/doctrine/model')),
            '.orm.xml'
        ));
        $driver = new Definition(XmlDriver::class, array($fileLocator));

        new DoctrineOrmMappingsPass(
            $driver,
            array("Acme\Database\Component\Demo\Model"),
            array('your_bundle.manager_name'),
            'your_bundle.orm_enabled'
        );
```

doctrine configuration

```
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
```

I get No mapping information to process but there are some entities at this namespace Acme\Database\Component\Demo\Model and the mappig xml files at /Resources/config/doctrine/model

```
$ run php bin/console make:migration -v

In NoMappingFound.php line 13:

  [Doctrine\Migrations\Provider\Exception\NoMappingFound]
  No mapping information to process
```

any suggestion

Comment: just a stupid idea, but you probably have wrapped your last call in `$container->addCompilerPass(...)` right?

Comment: @Jakumi yes i did

Comment: have you checked "manually" (by instantiating the loader/driver at that position) that it can actually find the files? tbh, I'm not quite familiar with the DoctrineOrmMappingsPass, so let's eliminate other causes first ;o/